# ¿Como puedo sumar las veces que se repite un nodo en un árbol binario?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios

En un árbol binario tengo que almacenar un grupo de datos dentro de cada nodo, esos datos son: Id, Nombres, Apellidos, Sueldo y Departamentos, el objetivo es sumar los sueldos que se pagan a los empleados por cada departamento, es decir:
El departamento de física paga $1568 en sueldo.
El departamento de mecánica paga $3098 en sueldo.
El problema existe en que no se sabe que departamentos estén dentro del árbol, el mismo árbol se debe encargar de conocer cuando departamentos diferentes existen y sumar los sueldos de esos departamentos y sumarlo, para posteriormente ser mostrado, he intentado varias cosas pero no puedo llegar a resolver.
Si me ayudan con pautas para realizar esto se los agradecería mucho, no quería llegar a preguntar en esto he intentarlo hacer yo pero el tiempo de entrega se me agota y tengo mas proyectos que realizar :(

Comment: Tiene pinta de que quieres el árbol por un lado y una clase que sea capaz de resolver las preguntas que le planteas. 

Personalmente lo que haría sería generar un HashMap y recorrer el arbol entero. Para cada nodo sacas el departamento y el sueldo y lo añades al hashMap de forma acumulativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Planteamiento

Este ejercicio se puede resolver fácilmente con un objeto de la clase **HashMap**, que almacene los pares de valores **<String, Integer>**, suponiendo que el nombre del departamento se almacene como String y el sueldo de cada empleado como un Integer (si no fueran esos tipos de datos, los puedes cambiar por otros sin problema).

## Tipo de recorrido del árbol

El algoritmo planteado a continuación plantea un **enfoque iterativo**, por lo que terminar la implementación con un **recorrido en anchura** será casi inmediato. De todas formas, adaptarlo a un recorrido en profundidad no supondría dificultad.

## Algoritmo

```
import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.HashMap; 

public class EjercicioDepartamentos{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashMap<String, Integer> sueldosDepartamento = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Para todo nodo en el árbol binario: // esto dependerá de tu tipo de recorrido
            if(sueldosDepartamento.containsKey(nodo.departamento)){
                // ya se ha almacenado al menos un sueldo en el map
                int sueldos = sueldosDepartamento.get(nodo.departamento);            

                // sumamos el sueldo del empleado a la suma de sueldos del departamento
                sueldosDepartamento.replace(nodo.departamento, sueldos + nodo.sueldo);
            }else{
                // introducimos el nuevo departamento en el map, junto al sueldo del empleado
                sueldosDepartamento.put(nodo.departamento, nodo.sueldo);
            }

        // Mostramos los resultados por pantalla
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : sueldosDepartamento.entrySet())  
            System.out.println("Departamento = " + entry.getKey() + 
                             ", Suma de sueldos = " + entry.getValue()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya pude avanzar gracias a tu ayuda, pero aun tengo problema y es que nuca se cumple la condición if, al pesar que esta sea correcta, quizás me equivoque a la hora de agregar tu código al mio.

Answer (score 0):

Este seria el codigo que tengo pero el cual falla, si me podrian ayudar a ver mi error a la hora de implementar este codigo, por fa

```
public void ResumenSueldos(Nodo nodo){
        HashMap<String, Double> sueldosDepartamento = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        if(nodo == null){
            return;
        } else{
            ResumenSueldos(nodo.getIzquierdo());
            ResumenSueldos(nodo.getDerecho());
            if(sueldosDepartamento.containsKey(nodo.getDato().getDepartamento())){
                double sueldos = sueldosDepartamento.get(nodo.getDato().getSueldo());
                sueldosDepartamento.replace(nodo.getDato().getDepartamento(), sueldos + nodo.getDato().getSueldo());
            }else{
                sueldosDepartamento.put(nodo.getDato().getDepartamento(), nodo.getDato().getSueldo());
            }
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entry : sueldosDepartamento.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("Departamento = " + entry.getKey() + 
                             ", Suma de sueldos = " + entry.getValue()); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Añado otra respuesta porque todavía no tengo suficiente reputación para poder comentar en el último post de Deither*

### Cambio nº 1

El objeto HashMap debe acompañarte a lo largo del recorrido del árbol, es decir, **se inicializa una sola vez**, y por cada nodo que recorras se le añaden nuevos datos.

Dicho esto, debes cambiar esta parte del código:

```
public void ResumenSueldos(Nodo nodo){
        HashMap<String, Double> sueldosDepartamento = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

por esta otra:

```
public void ResumenSueldos(Nodo nodo, HashMap<String,Double> sueldosDepartamento){
```

La **inicialización del objeto HashMap deberás realizarla fuera de la función ResumenSueldos,** ya sea en la función main() o donde desees.

### Cambio nº 2

Además, el siguiente código también debe ser eliminado:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entry : sueldosDepartamento.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("Departamento = " + entry.getKey() + 
                             ", Suma de sueldos = " + entry.getValue()); 
        }
```

Ya que esto se debe ejecutar una vez se haya recorrido **todo el árbol**, no cada vez que visites un nodo. Consecuentemente, también deberás mover este código a la función main().